# Batch Upload from Local to Webserver is not doing anything

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I want to upload a directory to my Webserver each day (overriding).

I created an batch-file (my first) but it is doing nothing.

Vsftp is installed on Debian 10, which runs a joomla stack at /var/www/joomla

```
@echo off

REM FTP server details
set FTP_SERVER=https://example.de:22
set FTP_USERNAME=root
set FTP_PASSWORD=passw

REM Local and remote directories
set LOCAL_DIR=V:\01 All
set REMOTE_DIR=/images/04 All

REM Create a temporary file to store FTP commands
set FTP_SCRIPT=%TEMP%\ftp_script.txt

REM Generate FTP commands
echo open %FTP_SERVER% > %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo %FTP_USERNAME% >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo %FTP_PASSWORD% >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo binary >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo cd %REMOTE_DIR% >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo lcd %LOCAL_DIR% >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo mput *.* >> %FTP_SCRIPT%
echo bye >> %FTP_SCRIPT%

REM Execute FTP commands using VSFTPD
ftp -s:%FTP_SCRIPT%

REM Clean up temporary file
del %FTP_SCRIPT%
```

Comment: What does it mean *"it is doing nothing"*. Doesn't it output anything? What did you do to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably stray spaces.

You are explicitly adding a space to each line to your ftp-script (`echo string[SPACE]>> ...` (which don't matter with most commands, but are critical with `username` and `password`: "`MySecret` " does not match "`MySecret`").

You can avoid those spaces with `(echo %FTP_PASSWORD%) >> %FTP_SCRIPT%` or you echo all lines at once to the file instead of every single line one at a time:

```
REM Generate FTP commands
(
    echo open %FTP_SERVER%
    echo %FTP_USERNAME%
    echo %FTP_PASSWORD%
    echo binary
    echo cd %REMOTE_DIR%
    echo lcd %LOCAL_DIR%
    echo mput *.*
    echo bye 
)  > "%FTP_SCRIPT%"
```

Be sure to not have any unintended trailing spaces in that part of the script.

Comment: I'd also recommend quotes around `%FTP_SCRIPT%` in case their Windows username has spaces.